# I want to compute gini, roc and auc for large datasets. Which platform should I use?

Tags: statistics

Shall I use Spark? Will pandas dataframe with scikit suffice?

Comment: Your question has been migrated to [Softwarerecs.se]. The audience here are not all statisticians, so please [edit] your question and put some links in that explain abbreviations and link to the software you mention. Also, make sure your question meets the others [standards for the site](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Even on 'stats' your question misses detail. What is large? In what form are these datasets? What do you mean with 'platform' - possibly 'software', which leaves the question: what OS?

Comment: Also, do you have a budget?